# AngularJS layered date filter for database submission

Tags: angularjs, date, jdbc

I am having trouble with date submissions to a database.  When date and time are both needed, I parse the values from the database as a timestamp, which gives me the value of the date and time in milliseconds since 1970.  Using the AngularJS date filter, I am able to display the value in a user-friendly way.

```
$filter('date')(1380292078000, 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a');   =>   09/27/2013 10:27 AM
```

But this format as a timestamp when I send the value back to the database, my code throws an error.  The database wants the date to be displayed in a different format.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Timestamp format must be yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss
```

So I add a second filter to convert the value date representation of the millisecond count (the user might have changed the value), but I am just getting a clone of the first date representation.

```
$filter('date')('09/27/2013 10:27 AM', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss')   =>   09/27/2013 10:27 AM
```

Here is a [link to the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dSP35/) I wrote to test this.  Are we not able to stack filter conversions on top of each other?  I had a thought to convert the first conversion result into milliseconds to use as a source for the second conversion, but I didn't see a method to accomplish this in the date documentation.  If that would be the only solution, though, I am sure I could whip something up.  Because Java has mostly deprecated functions to work with dates, I feel it would be simpler to handle this on the Javascript/AngularJS side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date filter will only work with a JSON date string (see [source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/dc57fe97e1be245fa08f25143302ee9dd850c5c9/src/ng/filter/filters.js#L383)).

You can get around your problem by converting to a date object:

```
$scope.date2 = $filter('date')(new Date($scope.date), 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss')
```

See [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jimschubert/dSP35/1/)

**However...** You should be validating and formatting this input on the server side. You can't trust data coming from a javascript application to be in the correct or expected format.  I'd recommend just posting back `$scope.date` and allowing the server to format in your database format. By doing the `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss` formatting on the client-side, you're tightly coupling your user interface to database implementation and that's generally considered a bad idea.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.  I think that the jdbc java call to the database isn't going through at all because of the timestamp data type.  If I change it to date, it might offer me more flexibility.  I was thinking to attempt the call with timestamp and additional server side validation, but needed the conversion first.